# mysql select query - to match one field with the other field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find records that has the following scenario.

```
ID |     name   |      email
 1      Robert        robert@gmail.com
 2      William       bill@gmail.com
 3      Michael       michael@gmail.com
 4      Micahel       mike@gmail.com
```

Based on the above table, I want to find the records where the "name" is contained in the "email field", here record 1 and 3 should be the output and not 2 and 4. Is there any way I can do this comparison?

I tried reading about regex but couldn't find anything. If it's comparison of same value, it will be straightforward, but I am not having any clue for this one. I thought of `LIKE` but looks like this cannot have field names.

Comment: @bobby - yeah i did that already.

Comment: Good. There's no need for [unnecessary politeness](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Also there's no need for `Thank you` comments, as they're considered as unnecessary noise. An upvote is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact syntax will depend on how you want to define the relationship.

Are you looking for the name anywhere in the email address? (This will be slow)

```
select id,name,email
from your_table
where email like concat('%',name,'%')
```

Just at the beginning of the email address?

```
select id,name,email
from your_table
where email like concat(name,'%')
```

Just before the @ sign?

```
select id,name,email
from your_table
where email like concat(name,'@%')
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it was a quick reply and it helps. @all thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LIKE`, you just have to use it in combination with `CONCAT`.

```
SELECT
    ID,
    name,
    email
FROM
    yourTable
WHERE
    email LIKE CONCAT(name, '%');
```

The `CONCAT` will return a string which can be used to match against `email` via `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email LIKE (CONCAT('%',name,'%'))
```

Comment: maybe using ILIKE would do a better job as it's case insensitive

Comment: @Voooza: Since when is `LIKE` case-sensitive?

Comment: I was just editing my comment. Sorry I forgot about mysql being insensitive at all :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from your_table where lower(substring_index(email,'@',1))=lower(name)
```